# how to make continue function in python goes back to a specific line inside the loop, not through the entire loop

Tags: python, function, loops

As a beginner, I want to make continue function in Python to go back to a specific line inside the loop not to start over without making double while loops, I will explain more by code.

The following program aims to take a name (letters only) and age (numbers only) from the user until valid inputs are given:

```
while True :
    name=input ('please enter your first name with no numbers ')
    if not name.isalpa():
        print('incorrect input, please enter another input')
        continue
    age = input ('''please enter your age 'numbers only' ''')
    if not age.isdecimal():
        # I want to use continue heer to jump back to the
        # age input line again not to the start of the loop
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your intention is to read only one name and one age or more than one? Asking this because of the while true loop...

Comment: hello Roberto, the written program just to explain the main question which is how to make (continue) function go to a specific line inside the loop, not to the start of the loop?

Comment: how can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
while True :
    name=input ('please enter your first name with no numbers ')
    while(!name.isalpa()):
        print('incorrect input, please enter another input')
        name=input ('please enter your first name with no numbers ')
    age = input ('''please enter your age 'numbers only' ''')
    while(!age.isdecimal()):
        print('incorrect input, please enter another input')
        age=input ('''please enter your age 'numbers only' ''')
```

Comment: but still, how could I make continue function go back to a specific line?

Comment: `Continue` will again start from the beginning of the loop.if you want to make it go back to a specific line, it can also be achieved but not necessarily with continue..

Answer (score 0):

That's for sure a bad design. You should validate one input and then ask for another. But you can accomplish what you are asking for with an additional boolean variable:

```
isNameOk = False

while True :
    if not isNameOk:
        name=input ('please enter your first name with no numbers ')
        if not name.isalpa():
            print('incorrect input, please enter another input')
            continue
        isNameOk = True
    age = input ('''please enter your age 'numbers only' ''')
    if not age.isdecimal():
        print('incorrect input, please enter another input')
        continue
```

But I would strongly suggest something like this with two `while`s:

```
name = input ('please enter your first name with no numbers ')
while not name.isalpha():
    name = input('please enter your first name with no numbers ')
            
age = input('please enter your age numbers only')
while not age.isdecimal():
    age = input('please enter your age numbers only')
```

Comment: I know it's a bad design, its only for explaining my question which is how to make continue function to go back for a specific line inside the loop, not to the start, hence your first design could be a way of doing that.